# how to define a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have got the following in a header file for a class:

```
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
```

In the class description, I have the following protected member:

```
vector<Point2D>         samples;
```

Point2D is defined as a class

during compile time I get lots of errors (C2143, C4430 and C2238)

Any ideas?

Comment: It's `std::vector`.

Comment: Retagged: I assume you are asking a c++ question with incorrect tagging and not a C# question with wildly incorrect syntax and concepts.

Comment: Please include the actual error messages for those of us who don't have the time to Google your error codes. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add more code? Or what the errors are? Usually it works just fine with std::vector<MyClass> sampleVec; so its something wrong with how you did that.

Comment: You are including the header file where `Point2D` is declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link to the standard Vector. 
`std::vector`

Answer (score 5):

Unless in some other part of your code you are defining a namespace, you need to use `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
...
std::vector<Point2D> samples;
```